# Problems using \nocite with multibbl

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, errors, subdividing

I get some problems with package `multibbl`.

On one hand, if I write
`\bibliographystyle{ref}{alpha}`
`\bibliography{ref}{books}`
and anything more until `\appendix`, a new section or `\end{document}` I get the error `Paragraph ended before \bibliography was complete. <to be read again> \par`, but I fix this writing after that `\nocite{}`.

On the other hand, if I want to appear all references, even those which I don't cite, when I place `\nocite{*}` instead of `\nocite{}` the `*` also appears in the final `file.pdf`.

Someone knows why this works in this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`multibbl`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multibbl) redefines the `\bibliography` command to require *three*, not two, arguments.

> The \bibliography command has been redefined to take three required arguments: the first is the name of the auxiliary file, the second is the argument that the standard command has and the third is the the title of the bibliographic section,...

In your code summary the command is only given two arguments, so LaTeX is still scanning for the third argument.  Similarly, the other commands, including `\nocite` require an extra argument.

Here is a minimal working example:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multibbl}

\newbibliography{oneb}
\newbibliography{twob}

\begin{document}
Text


\nocite{oneb}{*}
\nocite{twob}{*}
\bibliographystyle{oneb}{plain}
\bibliography{oneb}{one}{First bib}
\bibliographystyle{twob}{alpha}
\bibliography{twob}{two}{Second bib}


\end{document}
```

with `one.bib` containing

```
@Article{oneart,
  author =   {Author, O.},
  title =    {Title One},
  journal =  {One J.},
  year =     2010
}
```

and `two.bib`

```
@Book{twobook,
  author =   {Author, Two},
  title =    {Book Two},
  publisher =    {Multi-publish},
  year =     2005
}
```

Run latex on the main file, then `bibtex oneb` and `bibtex twob`, then run latex on the main file again.

However, if I had to produce these multiple types of bibliographies, I would choose biblatex instead, because of its rich feature set.

Comment: Thanks. I had tried writing \nocite with 2 arguments and also \bibliography with 3, but surely not at the same time or with them disordered and then I got errors also.

Comment: Good to hear this works.  You need buy in to the whole of the package's set-up to make it work.