# How to create a processing tool for multibbl in TeXworks?

Tags: bibtex, texworks

As explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95944/problems-using-nocite-with-multibbl) (or also [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/383538/multiple-bibliographies-with-multibbl)), package `multibbl` allows building multiple bibliographies by means of

```
\usepackage{multibbl}

\newbibliography{oneb}
\newbibliography{twob}
...
```

and to get it works one has to run first `latex` with the main file and later `bibtex oneb` and `bibtex twob` before to run again `latex` with the main file.
In TexWorks processing tools `BibteX` argument is `$basename` so it applies to the main tex file and not to the `newbibliography` names. Further, it is thus as it is integrated in the `pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX` tool. Therefore, one has to run `bibtex` commands by hand.

Is there some way to add a new processing tool specifying to it that `bibtex` has to apply to the `newbibliography` names?

I copy a MWE (as asked for in comments) from the first link above. Let the main TeX file be `test.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multibbl}

\newbibliography{oneb}
\newbibliography{twob}

\begin{document}
Text


\nocite{oneb}{*}
\nocite{twob}{*}
\bibliographystyle{oneb}{plain}
\bibliography{oneb}{one}{First bib}
\bibliographystyle{twob}{alpha}
\bibliography{twob}{two}{Second bib}


\end{document}
```

And let the bib files be `one.bib`:

```
@Article{oneart,
  author =   {Author, O.},
  title =    {Title One},
  journal =  {One J.},
  year =     2010
}
```

and `two.bib`

```
@Book{twobook,
  author =   {Author, Two},
  title =    {Book Two},
  publisher =    {Multi-publish},
  year =     2005
}
```

All in the same folder, and tentatively, also with other TeX and `.bib` files.

Thank you!

Comment: Would you please give a MWE for testing? If that package does things correctly latexmk might do the job out of the box.

Comment: Done. Just copied from the first link above.

Comment: @iago we generally do not like going off site for MWEs, external links disappear over time thus making your question unusable for others who wee it in the future. That is why we always ask to have the MWE added directly to the question.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like multibbl works fine with latexmk. I don't use TeXWorks but others should be able to let you know how to set latexmk processing up under TeXWorks. An alternative is to set up arara processing up and tell arara what you need to do (as special comments in your file.