# Multiple Bibliographies with multibbl, how to with Texmaker

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, texmaker

I want to have two seperate bibliographies in my document, one for books and one for articles.

I am trying to use the `multibbl` package and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/96019/156345) example.

The code looks like this:

test_article.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multibbl}

\newbibliography{books}
\newbibliography{articles}

\begin{document}
Text \cite{books}{testBook} and \cite{articles}{testArticle}

\bibliographystyle{books}{plain}
\bibliography{books}{bookBib}{Book References}
\bibliographystyle{articles}{alpha}
\bibliography{articles}{articleBib}{Article References}

\end{document}
```

With the two bibliography files:

bookBib.bib:

```
@book{testBook,
  title={This is a test book},
  author={Book, Author},
  year={2021},
  publisher={Book Publisher}
}
```

articleBib.bib:

```
@article{testArticle,
  title={This is a test article},
  author={Article, Author},
  journal={Test Hournal},
  volume={1},
  number={1},
  pages={1--2},
  year={2021},
  publisher={Article Publisher}
}
```

I configured Texmaker to run `PdfLaTex + Biblatex + PdfLatex (x2) + Show Pdf`.

When I hit F1 I get the following error message:

*I found no \citation commands---while reading file test_article.aux I found no \bibdata command---while reading file test_article.aux I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file test_article.aux (There were 3 error messages)*

The linked answer mentions that bibtex must be run on both bib files. So I opened the terminal and tried:

```
bibtex articles
bibtex books
```

This executes without any errors or warnings in the terminal. However, when I go back to Texmaker and try F1, I still get the very same error message. At this point I don't know what to do.

**Questions**:

- What is the correct way, step-by-step, to compile this example with Texmaker?
- Is there a way to automate the manual bibtex calls in Texmaker such that I don't have to use the terminal?

Ideally, I just want to use F1 for compilation like when I have only a single bibliography.

Comment: you say you configured the editor to run biblatex?? but you are not using biblatex at all, that would be biber, but I think you meant bibtex. You are getting the error as you are running bibtex on the standard aux file but you have diverted all bib entries to the two extra aux files for articles and books so you want to run bibtex on those, or just make your editor run pdflatex and not bibtex at all and run bibtex by hand as you have done if you change the citations

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks, I managed to compile the example. However I would still like to have a way to do that automatically, without always opening the terminal and running bibtex.

Comment: I don't use texmaker but I'm sure a texmaker user will pass by and answer saying how to set up a config.